# Datetime format from iPhone settings and GMT offset

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter, datetime-format

I have string with date time format e.g.: `2013-05-28 10:56:31`

How can I format this string to the iPhone default format? (in iPhone settings)

And how to set datetime in GMT plus time shift offset (set in iphone too). e.g. GMT+1

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use NSDateFormatter to achieve this.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-05-28 10:56:31";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

//Special Locale for fixed dateStrings
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];

//Assuming the dateString is in GMT+00:00
//formatter by default would be set to local timezone 
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date =[formatter dateFromString:dateString];

//After forming the date set local time zone to formatter    
NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[formatter setTimeZone:localTimeZone];

NSString *newTimeZoneDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",newTimeZoneDateString);
```

A few pointers for using dateFormatter.

1. If the string don't contain any information about timezone and it is not in same timezone as in the device always set the timezone to the dateFormatter.
2. For fixed format dateStrings always use `en_US_POSIX` locale
3. NSDate when logged in console always show in GMT+00:00. NSDate don't have timezone, it just differs when represented in different timezone.
4. Convert the formed date to any timezone, by setting new timezone to formatter. Formatter never changes the date it just recalculates how it will be represented in this new timezone.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what to do after? this what you wrote convert my string to date in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss? but why en_US_POSIX? what if someone wouldn't have this locale? and what about that timezone?

Comment: @Miras It is recommended to use this special locale for fixed date format strings. Have a read here [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW5). I will update my answer to include timezone conversion.

Comment: ok I'll watch it. For this time thanks and I write here how this help me.

Comment: I try it, it's nice, but still not what I want. I need this time with format of device, system short format, or something like this. And timezone what you wrote is for timezone UTC, but I need for system timezone. e.g. if I print result of this     NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; I get Europe/Prague (GMT+02:00) offset 7200 (Daylight) and I want to add these 2hours to mi time format.

Comment: @Miras By default dateFormatter will have localTimeZone. If you know the timezone of the dateString set that timeZone to the formatter when you are trying to form the date. After date is formed you can set any other timeZone to formatter and convert the date formed to a string of your choice.

Comment: wau I am starting to understand it. But if I try this code, and change my timezone on iPhone. for example to london it is GMT+1. And if I print my time I see this 2013-05-28 09:56:31. I think this should be 2013-05-28 11:56:31, don't you think? Because 2013-05-28 10:56:31 should be GMT+0

Comment: @Miras I have edited my answer and added a few pointers. Please go through them and find the answer yourself :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you wrote, but still don't know how to make it. I think I have to read properly NSDateFormatter and NSTimeZone manual

Comment: @Miras I have changed the code once again. See if this what you expect.

Comment: yes yes yes, this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot. Last think what I need is format that date to format what I need, someone have 12hour format and someone 24h etc. But I'll read that NSDateFormatter manual, and then I'll be smarter. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation about [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically `dateFromString`, which returns "A date representation of string interpreted using the receiver’s current settings."