# How to define which is (24/12) hour format on device?

Tags: ios, locale, date-format

How can i get information about which hours format prefer user?
Is it any `[application instace].prefferedTimeFormat` or something like this?

[image]

Comment: I do believe `NSDateFormatter` [automatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html) takes care of this preference. Unless, you need to read this setting for some other reason, just use `NSDateFormatter` for displaying date strings in your UI.

Comment: There is a couple methods without any NSDateFormatter usage. And inside i want to know whitch format user set (prefer) in iPhone settings.. I know it's bad to do not use NSDateFormatter while you work with Date&Time, but i've no any desire to refactor this methods. Only waht to know user setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more like a hack can you try with this. If you use `NSDateFormatterMediumSytle` if user has turned on 24 hour format the dateFormat would be `H:mm:ss` if it's not turned on the format would be `h:mm:ss a`.

If you just want to set the format based on the user preferences just set the style of date and time to formatter. It will take care of the rest.

```
- (BOOL)is24HourFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    return [dateFormatter.dateFormat isEqualToString:@"H:mm:ss"];
}
```

Comment: It's work fine. Thx a lot. But is it really no any getter for this option from settings? It mean you always have to use NSDateFormatter. But what if server return an NSString with 24hour format time and i heve to change it local on device if i need it..

Comment: @EvgeniyS Yes, for changing the dateFormats you always need to use NSDateFormatter. If you are receiving a dateString from server, set that format to the dateFormatter, form the date and then convert the date to the dateFormat you want. I have given a detailed [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16790952/767730) regarding this, you might find it useful.