# NSDateFormatter: how to convert "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 04:56:15 GMT" to local time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm getting this date/time from server, I need to convert it to local `NSDate`, how do I set the `NSDateFormatter`'s` format string? Should i just remove the first day of week string?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *dateString = @"Wed, 23 Oct 2013 04:56:15 GMT";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *localDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@",localDateString);
```

For more details refer a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16790952/767730) of mine

Comment: Hi what does the `setLocale` do?

Comment: @hzxu Do care to read the documentation of [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). Look for `Parsing Date Strings` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:@"Wed, 23 Oct 2013 04:56:15 GMT"];

NSDateFormatter *dfchange = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dfchange setDateFormat:@"dd. MMM YYYY"];
NSString *s = [dfchange stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:-

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSString *dateStr=@"Wed, 23 Oct 2013 04:56:15 GMT";
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *changeDate=[dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"changeDate=%@",changeDate);
NSString *str=[dateFormat stringFromDate:changeDate];

//getting your local time
NSTimeZone *tz=[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
//setting yourlocal time
[dateFormat setTimeZone:tz];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
//Setting your desired format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy Z"];
NSString *newDate=[dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"new date=%@",newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *locale1 = [NSLocale currentLocale];
        [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *d=[dateformatter dateFromString:@"2013-10-22"];
        NSString *base = @"dd-MMM-yyyy,EEEE";
        NSString *format1 = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:base options:0 locale:locale1];
        [dateformatter setDateFormat:format1];

NSString* FinalString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:d]
```

**Let me know if you have any problem.**

Answer (score 0):

***this will work***

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Wed, 29 Tue 2014 18:22:18 GMT";   
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
[format setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];   
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
//output    
NSLog(@"%@",date1);
```